# passing form parameters from one form to another in the same page

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, request

I'm trying to grab values from form1 and form2 post submit respectively.
The only difference is that when i submit form2, I need form1 values as well.

## Form 1

```
<form action="send_value1" method="POST">
      Input1: <input type="text" name="input1">
      Input2: <input type="text" name="input2">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit_form1">
</form>
```

## Form 2

```
<form action="send_value2" method="POST">
      Input3: <input type="text" name="input3">
      Input4: <input type="text" name="input4">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit_form2">
</form>
```

In py file, I'm trying to fetch using POST method

```
@app.route("/page", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def to_do():
  
    if request.method == "POST":

        if request.form['submit'] == 'submit_form1':

            data1 = request.form['input1']
            data2 = request.form['input2']

        if request.form['submit'] == 'submit_form2':

            data3 = request.form['input3']
            data4 = request.form['input4']

            # Here I want to grab values of form1 as well
```

I tried a few things to grab form1 values in form2 but to no avail. Any help on how to approach this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how the forms work? Does the user complete form 1, submit it, and then complete form 2 at which point you want to grab for form 1's values or does the user not have to submit form 1 when completing form 2? If you can explain the user flow behind the forms it might help.

Comment: @Kakedis Both forms are independent of each other. The user does not have to submit form 1 if they want to submit form 2